# How do I turn off the cascade of tones that happens every time I end a call?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, audio

I have a Galaxy S phone, and every time a call ends it plays a cascading series of 4 tones.  Regardless of how my phone's ringtone volume is set - e.g. even if I have it on silent mode - these tones play.  It's especially annoying when I'm wearing my headset, which seals against my ear, making these tones much louder than the call was.  I have to jerk my headset away from my ear unless I want to endure it, and I don't like to complain, but it's f-ing LOUD.  Is there any way that I can disable this end of call sound?  It doesn't matter which headset I use; this is a function of the phone itself.  Can't find anything in the manual about it, either.

Answer (score 3):

On my phone (Galaxy S) it's in `Settings -> Call settings -> All calls -> Call status tones -> Call end tone`.